# Rspec test failing miserably

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, railstutorial.org

So I've seen several questions on here somewhat similar to mine, but not quite close enough to help me figure out what my issue is...so any help on what i'm doing wrong would be appreciated:  (I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial so info on how i've deviated from his examples would be particularly helpful)...thx

```
I'm throwing the following 2 errors:

Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action 
 Failure/Error: before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `put' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007f8943728688>
 # ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:78:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Users controller submitting  to the update action 
 Failure/Error: before { put user_path(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `put' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007f8944a85ff0>
 # ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.06 seconds
56 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:79 # Authentication authorization as     wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action 
rspec ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:62 # Authentication authorization for non- signed-in users in the Users controller submitting to the update action
```

My Code is as follows:

spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  # FOR STATIC SIGN IN PAGE
  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  # FOR SIGNIN PROCESS
  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  # FOR AUTHORIZING WHICH ACCOUNTS CAN DO WHAT
  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do
        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

My spec/features/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  # TESTING STATIC PROFILE PAGE
  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } # Code to make a user variable
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  # TESTING STATIC SIGNUP PAGE
  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_title("Sign up") }
  end

  # TESTING SIGN UP PROCESS
  describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_title('Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end

    end
  end

  # TESTING EDITING FUNCTIONALITY
  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do 
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      # it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      # needed if using gravatar
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end

  end

end
```

My spec/support/utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.has_selector?('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
  end
end

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara.
  # cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

My controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Authentication App..."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

end
```

& Lastly my views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any and all help as to the correct fix would be greatly appreciated. thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're following the Rails Tutorial, you need to downgrade your Capybara version to 1.1.2 and move your specs into the `spec/requests` directory. Update your Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
```

If you plan on using Capybara 2.0, I suggest reading this:

http://alindeman.github.io/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: thanks man - seems like a pain in the ass...so basically i have to go back through and put all the tests that aren't capybara back into spec/requests???  But keep the capybara tests in the /features folder??  (I'm sticking w/ the new 2+ capybara - that link was very helpful)

Comment: If you're following Michael Hartl's tutorial, just move your files from `spec/features` to `spec/requests`. Take a look at the [sample_app](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed) on GitHub.

Comment: If any one else has issues w/ these specific errors...I was able to get it w/ the help from these guys answers...Just recreate a duplicate authentication_pages_spec.rb in the spec/requests/folder...strip out the [describe "submitting to the update action" do] test and place it in the newly duplicated file.  (but don't forget to also add the let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

Comment: it looks like he's still using that older version of capybara...I've just got all capybara tests in /features & other tests in /requests (which seems to be working - the errors from the post at least worked when they were tossed into /requests

Answer (score 1):

`put, get, post, delete` and those methods used for controller tests are not available in feature tests.

You should be "submitting" the `put` through a button action/ajax/etc..., not posting to the controller as you would a controller test, when writing feature tests.

Comment: thanks kwon - so should I put these tests into a new directory.  Or could you point me in the right direction?  Sorry - still pretty new to rspec & tdd...

Comment: i.e, I can just remove the describe "submitting to the update action" test altogether obviously, but I would think that wouldn't be the best idea...thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: **you messing request (`capybara`) tests with functional tests**.

In `capybara` you should describe user steps, as such

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Website access" do
  context "when I am a registered user" do
    it "should let me in" do
      page.fill_in 'Email',    with: 'vader@deathstar.com'
      page.fill_in 'Password', with: 'mydearluke'
      page.click_link 'Let me in'

      page.should have_content('Welcome, cheif!')
    end
  end

  context "when I am not a registered user" do
    it "should not let me in" do
      page.fill_in 'Email',    with: 'jabba.h@tatooine.com'
      page.fill_in 'Password', with: 'wormsarmageddon'
      page.click_link 'Let me in'

      page.should have_content('Incorrect credentials!')
    end
  end      
end
```

Functional tests operate at a lower level, since you need to use HTTP verbs as `put`, `get`, `post`, `delete` to communicate with the application you're testing.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do
  context "when I am registered user" do
    it "should let me in" do
      post :create, email: 'vader@deathstar.com', password: 'mydearluke'

      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  context "when I am not a registered user" do
    it "should not let me in" do
      post :create, email: 'jabba.h@tatooine.com', password: 'wormsarmageddon'

      response.should_not be_success
    end
  end      
end
```

A few things to notice here:

1. I'm using `post`, not `put`.
2. I'm specifying controller name in `describe` block, in contrast to a plain english desctiption like in capybara tests.
3. Functional tests specifies how exactly a `SessionController` should respond to a different user credentials (it should create a session for a good user, and scream back at a not registered one).

What you are trying to do is to use verbs from **functional** tests in your **request** (capybara) tests. This is wrong.

A recap:

1. use `visit` and `click_link`/`click_button` in `capybara` tests.
2. use HTTP verbs (`put`, `get`, `post`, `delete`) in functional tests.
3. use [`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for user authentication.

Comment: I appreciate it man - this was very helpful (apparently i dont' have enough points or something to upvote your answers)